# should I use ElasticSearch _type as routing

Tags: elasticsearch

I usually query ES by _type, so I'm wondering if I use _type as routing parameter, would that be read/write performance better?
For example:
PUT my_index/my_type/1?routing=_type

My situation is that for some _types I only have a few million docs while other _types I may have a few billion docs, but they are all in one index. 
I'm afraid of the small _types docs located to each nodes, that may cause read performance bad. So I prefer the small _types only located on two or three nodes not all of nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Your question is too vague. The answer depends on your use case(s). Please explain in a bit more details what you're trying to achieve. As such, it's hard to properly answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Val, I modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `routing` parameter is not meant for allocating indices to specific nodes, but for allocating documents to specific shards within an index.

If you want to allocate your index to one or two specific nodes you can use [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html) where you can specify on which node the shards of a given index can be located.

For instance, if you decide that your small index can only be on `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2`, you'd run the following command:

```
PUT my_index/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.include._ip": "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2"
}
```

After running this, you'll see all the shards of `my_index` being reallocated to either `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.1.2`, but not to the other nodes of the cluster.

Comment: I can't understand why people need to route their data to different shards, my understanding is that: people route data to different shard just for routing their data to different node.

Comment: There was an [excellent blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing) by the ES folks that explains why and when routing can be used. Also have a look at [slide 31 of this presentation](http://fr.slideshare.net/ABCTalks/elastic-search-overview) which shows visually what routing is.